# Flexible AuthenticationExtractionWebFilter

Tags: java, authentication, spring

I decided to share with you a portion of my gateway project. It's an authentication extraction filter that extracts authentication claims without being coupled to any specific authentication mechanism. I have only one concrete `AuthenticationExtractor` implementation that parses JWT tokens, but you can simply create another implementation with no need to modify the existing code (in line with the open/closed principle)

I'm looking forward to hear your feedback

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.config.security.filter;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor.AuthenticationExtractor;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.util.ResponseWriter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * A {@link WebFilter} that tries to build an {@link Authentication} object from {@code ServerWebExchange}
 * and pass it to the {@link ReactiveSecurityContextHolder}.
 * <p>
 * This class is oblivious to the location of authentication claims and relies on an {@link AuthenticationExtractor} object
 * to actually build an {@code Authentication} from the exchange
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AuthenticationExtractionWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    private final AuthenticationExtractor authenticationExtractor;

    public AuthenticationExtractionWebFilter(AuthenticationExtractor authenticationExtractor) {
        this.authenticationExtractor = authenticationExtractor;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to build authentication claims from the exchange and write them to {@link reactor.util.context.Context}
     * for potential consumption of downstream filters
     * <p>
     * <b>This filter never attempts to authenticate the claims</b>. Authentication of claims may be performed
     * by a downstream filter or may have been already performed outside of this application entirely by an
     * authentication server that issued an authentication token contained in the request.
     * In the latter case, the associated {@code AuthenticationExtractor} may check the signing key
     * of an extracted authentication token. At any rate, this filter is completely agnostic to such details
     * <p>
     * If the exchange doesn't contain extractable claims in any supported location, the filter simply forwards the request
     * down the filter chain
     * <p>
     * If the extraction of authentication claims fails, the method sets the {@code 401 Unauthorized} status to the response
     * and returns an empty {@code Mono}
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Mono.just(authenticationExtractor)
                .filter(extractor -> extractor.isSupportedSource(exchange))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.empty())))
                .flatMap(extractor -> extractor.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange))
                .flatMap(authentication -> chain.filter(exchange)
                        .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication)
                ))
                .onErrorResume(AuthenticationException.class,
                        t -> ResponseWriter.writeUnauthorizedResponse(exchange, t));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.authorizationHeader;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.exception.AuthenticationSchemeNotFoundException;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.util.Objects;

@Getter
public class AuthorizationHeader {
    public static final String BEARER_SPACE = "bearer ";
    public static final String BASIC_SPACE = "basic ";
    private final String scheme;
    private final String credentials;

    public AuthorizationHeader(String authorizationHeaderString) {
        String scheme, credentials;
        try {
            String trimmedHeader = authorizationHeaderString.trim();
            int indexOfSpace = trimmedHeader.indexOf(" ");
            scheme = trimmedHeader.substring(0, indexOfSpace);
            credentials = trimmedHeader.substring(indexOfSpace).trim();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            scheme = "";
            credentials = "";
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationSchemeNotFoundException();
        }
        this.scheme = scheme;
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        AuthorizationHeader that = (AuthorizationHeader) o;
        return Objects.equals(scheme, that.scheme) && Objects.equals(credentials, that.credentials);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(scheme, credentials);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.ServerAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * Object that tries to build an {@link Authentication} from a provided {@link ServerWebExchange}.
 *
 * <p>Functionally similar to {@link ServerAuthenticationConverter}
 */
public interface AuthenticationExtractor {
    /**
     * Attempts to extract an {@link Authentication} object from a passed-in {@code ServerWebExchange}
     *
     * @param exchange {@code ServerWebExchange} that may contain an extractable authentication
     * @return {@code Mono} that may contain an extracted {@code Authentication}
     */
    Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(ServerWebExchange exchange);

    /**
     * Tests if this {@code AuthenticationExtractor} <em>may</em> extract an {@code Authentication} from
     * the provided {@code ServerWebExchange}
     *
     * <p>
     * <b>It provides no guarantee that an actual {@code Authentication} object will be extracted from the exchange.</b>
     * If the method returns {@code true}, it only means that the likelihood of a successful extraction is more than 0%.
     * For instance, it may mean that this {@code AuthenticationExtractor} discovers a specific request header whose value
     * it parses – which may not necessarily contain a valid token
     *
     * @param exchange {@code ServerWebExchange} that may be the source of an {@code Authentication}
     * @return {@code false} if {@code Authentication} extraction from the exchange by this {@code AuthenticationExtractor}
     * is impossible, {@code true} if it <em>may</em> result in a successful extraction
     */
    boolean isSupportedSource(ServerWebExchange exchange);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * An {@link AuthenticationExtractor} that extracts an {@code Authentication} object from the request's headers
 */
public interface HeaderAuthenticationExtractor extends AuthenticationExtractor {
    @Override
    default Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.just(exchange)
                .map(ServerWebExchange::getRequest)
                .map(ServerHttpRequest::getHeaders)
                .flatMap(this::tryExtractAuthentication);
    }

    Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(HttpHeaders headers);

    @Override
    default boolean isSupportedSource(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        HttpHeaders headers = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
        return areSupportedHeaders(headers);
    }

    boolean areSupportedHeaders(HttpHeaders headers);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.authorizationHeader.AuthorizationHeader;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * A {@link HeaderAuthenticationExtractor} that extracts an {@code Authentication} from the request's {@code Authorization} header
 *
 * @see <a href="https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-4.2">RFC 7235</a>
 */
public interface AuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor extends HeaderAuthenticationExtractor {
    @Override
    default Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(HttpHeaders headers) {
        return Mono.just(headers)
                .mapNotNull(h -> h.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
                .map(AuthorizationHeader::new)
                .flatMap(this::tryExtractAuthentication);
    }

    Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(AuthorizationHeader authorizationHeader);

    @Override
    default boolean areSupportedHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) {
        String header = headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        return isSupportedAuthorizationHeader(new AuthorizationHeader(header));
    }

    boolean isSupportedAuthorizationHeader(AuthorizationHeader header);
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.exception.UnsupportedAuthenticationSchemeException;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.authorizationHeader.AuthorizationHeader;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * An {@link AuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor} that extracts an {@code Authentication} from a {@code bearer}
 * token contained in the header
 *
 * @see <a href="https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750">RFC 6750</a>
 */
public interface BearerAuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor extends AuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor {
    @Override
    default Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(AuthorizationHeader authorizationHeader) {
        return Mono.just(authorizationHeader)
                .filter(this::isSupportedAuthorizationHeader)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(
                        new UnsupportedAuthenticationSchemeException(authorizationHeader.getScheme())))
                .map(AuthorizationHeader::getCredentials)
                .flatMap(this::tryExtractAuthentication);
    }

    Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(String bearerToken);

    @Override
    default boolean isSupportedAuthorizationHeader(AuthorizationHeader header) {
        return header.getScheme().equals(AuthorizationHeader.BEARER_SPACE.trim());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.constant.JWT;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A {@link BearerAuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor} that parses JSON Web Tokens
 */
@Component
public class JwtBearerAuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor
        implements BearerAuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor {

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(String token) {
        return Mono.just(token)
                .map(this::getClaims)
                .onErrorMap(JwtException.class, this::toBadCredentialsException)
                .map(this::toUpat);
    }

    private Claims getClaims(String jwt) {
        SecretKey hashedKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JWT.KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(hashedKey)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                .getBody();
    }

    private BadCredentialsException toBadCredentialsException(JwtException e) {
        return new BadCredentialsException(
                MessageFormat.format("Invalid token. {0}", e.getMessage()), e);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken toUpat(Claims claims) {
        Object subject = getPrincipalName(claims);
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = getGrantedAuthorities(claims);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(subject, null, authorities);
    }

    private Object getPrincipalName(Claims claims) {
        return claims.get(JWT.SUB);
    }

    private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Claims claims) {
        Object nullableRoles = claims.get(JWT.ROLES);
        return (nullableRoles instanceof List<?> roles) ?
                buildGrantedAuthoritiesFrom(roles) :
                Collections.emptyList();
    }

    private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> buildGrantedAuthoritiesFrom(List<?> roles) {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .toList();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.exception.UnsupportedAuthenticationSourceException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * An {@link AuthenticationExtractor} that delegates actual extraction to one of its aggregated {@code AuthenticationExtractor}s
 */
@Component
@Primary
public class CompositeAuthenticationExtractor implements AuthenticationExtractor {
    private final List<? extends AuthenticationExtractor> authenticationExtractors;

    public CompositeAuthenticationExtractor(List<? extends AuthenticationExtractor> authenticationExtractors) {
        this.authenticationExtractors = authenticationExtractors;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the first delegate that supports the provided exchange and delegates extraction to it
     *
     * @return {@code Mono} of {@code Authentication} on successful extraction,
     * {@code Mono.error(..)} of {@link UnsupportedAuthenticationSourceException} if none of the delegates
     * supports the source
     * @see AuthenticationExtractor#isSupportedSource
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(authenticationExtractors)
                .filter(extractor -> extractor.isSupportedSource(exchange))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new UnsupportedAuthenticationSourceException()))
                .next()
                .flatMap(extractor -> extractor.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange));
    }

    /**
     * Iterates over the delegates to see whether at least one of them supports {@code Authentication}
     * extraction from the provided exchange
     *
     * @return {@code true} if such a delegate is found, {@code false} otherwise
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isSupportedSource(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return authenticationExtractors.stream().anyMatch(extractor -> extractor.isSupportedSource(exchange));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.constant;

public class JWT {
    public static final String KEY = "jxgEQeXHuPq8VdbyYFNkANdudQ53YUn4";
    public static final String SUB = "sub";
    public static final String ROLES = "roles";

    private JWT() {
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.util;

import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class ResponseWriter {
    public static Mono<Void> writeUnauthorizedResponse(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable throwable) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(createErrorBody(throwable.getMessage())));
    }

    private static DataBuffer createErrorBody(String errorBody) {
        byte[] bytes = errorBody.getBytes();
        return DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance.wrap(bytes);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.exception;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

/**
 * A superclass for exceptions relating to invalid {@code Authentication} sources.
 * A raised exception of this type signals that authentication claims could not be obtained
 */
public abstract class AuthenticationSourceException extends AuthenticationException {
    public AuthenticationSourceException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.exception;

public class UnsupportedAuthenticationSourceException extends AuthenticationSourceException {
    public UnsupportedAuthenticationSourceException() {
        this("Could not extract authentication claims");
    }
    public UnsupportedAuthenticationSourceException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.exception;

public abstract class AuthenticationSchemeException extends AuthenticationSourceException {
    public AuthenticationSchemeException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.exception;

public class AuthenticationSchemeNotFoundException extends AuthenticationSchemeException {
    public AuthenticationSchemeNotFoundException() {
        this("An authentication scheme is expected");
    }

    public AuthenticationSchemeNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.exception;

import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class UnsupportedAuthenticationSchemeException extends AuthenticationSchemeException {
    public UnsupportedAuthenticationSchemeException(String scheme) {
        super(MessageFormat.format("Unsupported authentication scheme: {0}", scheme));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.config.security.filter;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor.AuthenticationExtractor;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.mock.web.server.MockServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebHandler;
import org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AuthenticationExtractionWebFilterTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private AuthenticationExtractionWebFilter filter;
    @Mock
    private AuthenticationExtractor authenticationExtractorMock;
    @Mock
    private WebFilterChain chainMock;

    @Test
    void testFilter_withNoAuthentication_exchangeFilteredFurther() {
        ServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/"));
        given(authenticationExtractorMock.isSupportedSource(exchange)).willReturn(false);
        given(chainMock.filter(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        StepVerifier.create(filter.filter(exchange, chainMock))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();

        then(chainMock).should().filter(exchange);
    }

    @Test
    void testFilter_withValidToken_exchangeFilteredFurther() {
        TestingAuthenticationToken token = new TestingAuthenticationToken("jack", "12345",
                List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user")));
        ServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/"));

        given(authenticationExtractorMock.isSupportedSource(exchange)).willReturn(true);
        given(authenticationExtractorMock.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.just(token));

        given(chainMock.filter(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        StepVerifier.create(filter.filter(exchange, chainMock))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();

        then(chainMock).should().filter(exchange);
    }

    @Test
    void testFilter_withValidToken_authenticationPassedToSecurityContextHolder() {
        String sub = "mickey_m";
        List<String> roles = List.of("user", "admin");
        TestingAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new TestingAuthenticationToken(
                sub, null, roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList()
        );

        MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest
                .get("/")
                .build();
        ServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(request);
        given(authenticationExtractorMock.isSupportedSource(exchange)).willReturn(true);
        given(authenticationExtractorMock.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.just(authenticationToken));

        WebHandler handlerMock = mock(WebHandler.class);
        given(handlerMock.handle(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        WebFilter authenticationAssertingFilter = (e, c) -> ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new AssertionError("No authentication")))
                .filter(a -> isExpectedAuthentication(a, sub, roles))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new AssertionError("Authentication doesn't match expected parameters")))
                .flatMap(a -> c.filter(e));

        WebFilterChain webFilterChain = new DefaultWebFilterChain(handlerMock, List.of(
                filter, authenticationAssertingFilter));

        StepVerifier.create(webFilterChain.filter(exchange))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    private boolean isExpectedAuthentication(Authentication authentication, Object principal, List<String> roleStrings) {
        List<String> roleStringsFromAuthentication = authentication.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .toList();
        return authentication.getPrincipal().equals(principal) &&
                roleStrings.containsAll(roleStringsFromAuthentication) &&
                roleStringsFromAuthentication.containsAll(roleStrings);
    }

    @Test
    void testFilter_ifBadCredentialsThrown_doesntFilter_returns401responseWithNonBlankBody() {
        MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest
                .get("/")
                .build();
        ServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(request);

        given(authenticationExtractorMock.isSupportedSource(exchange)).willReturn(true);
        given(authenticationExtractorMock.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange)).willThrow(new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token"));

        StepVerifier.create(filter.filter(exchange, chainMock))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();

        then(chainMock).should(never()).filter(exchange);

        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        assertThat(response).extracting(ServerHttpResponse::getStatusCode).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

        StepVerifier.create(((MockServerHttpResponse) response).getBodyAsString())
                .expectNextMatches(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.constant.JWT;
import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.authorizationHeader.AuthorizationHeader;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.server.MockServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

class JwtBearerAuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractorTest {
    private final JwtBearerAuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor extractor = new JwtBearerAuthorizationHeaderAuthenticationExtractor();

    @Test
    void testTryExtractAuthentication_withValidToken() {
        String principal = "mickey_m";
        List<String> roles = List.of("user", "admin");

        SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JWT.KEY.getBytes());

        String validToken = Jwts.builder()
                .claim(JWT.SUB, principal)
                .claim(JWT.ROLES, roles)
                .setExpiration(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)))
                .signWith(key)
                .compact();
        MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AuthorizationHeader.BEARER_SPACE + validToken)
                .build());

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken expectedAuthentication =
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(principal, null,
                        roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList());

        StepVerifier.create(extractor.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange))
                .expectNext(expectedAuthentication)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    void testTryExtractAuthentication_withExpiredToken() {
        SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JWT.KEY.getBytes());

        String expiredToken = Jwts.builder()
                .setExpiration(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1)))
                .signWith(key)
                .compact();

        testForInvalidToken(expiredToken);
    }

    private void testForInvalidToken(String invalidToken) {
        MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AuthorizationHeader.BEARER_SPACE + invalidToken)
                .build());

        StepVerifier.create(extractor.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange))
                .expectError(AuthenticationException.class)
                .verify();
    }

    @Test
    void testTryExtractAuthentication_withPhonySigningKey() {
        SecretKey phonyKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(UUID.randomUUID().toString().getBytes());

        String jwtWithPhonyKey = Jwts.builder()
                .setExpiration(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)))
                .signWith(phonyKey)
                .compact();

        testForInvalidToken(jwtWithPhonyKey);
    }

    @Test
    void testTryExtractAuthentication_withMalformedToken() {
        SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JWT.KEY.getBytes());

        String malformedToken = Jwts.builder()
                .setExpiration(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)))
                .signWith(key)
                .compact() + ".somebs";

        testForInvalidToken(malformedToken);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.authenticationExtractor;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.server.MockServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class CompositeAuthenticationExtractorTest {
    @Test
    void testTryExtractAuthentication_withoutDelegates_throws() {
        CompositeAuthenticationExtractor extractor = new CompositeAuthenticationExtractor(Collections.emptyList());
        MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/").build());
        StepVerifier.create(extractor.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange))
                .expectError(AuthenticationException.class)
                .verify();
    }

    @Test
    void testTryExtractAuthentication_withoutMatchingDelegates_throws() {
        MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/").build());
        AuthenticationExtractor delegateMock = mock(AuthenticationExtractor.class);
        given(delegateMock.isSupportedSource(exchange)).willReturn(false);

        CompositeAuthenticationExtractor extractor =
                new CompositeAuthenticationExtractor(List.of(delegateMock));

        StepVerifier.create(extractor.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange))
                .expectError(AuthenticationException.class)
                .verify();
    }

    @Test
    void testTryExtractAuthentication_withMatchingAuthenticators_delegates() {
        MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.get("/").build());
        AuthenticationExtractor authenticatorMock = mock(AuthenticationExtractor.class);
        given(authenticatorMock.isSupportedSource(exchange)).willReturn(true);

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> roles = Stream.of("user")
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .toList();
        TestingAuthenticationToken authentication = new TestingAuthenticationToken("mickey_m", "password", roles);
        given(authenticatorMock.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.just(authentication));

        CompositeAuthenticationExtractor compositeAuthenticationExtractor = new CompositeAuthenticationExtractor(List.of(authenticatorMock));

        StepVerifier.create(compositeAuthenticationExtractor.tryExtractAuthentication(exchange))
                .expectNext(authentication)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress VulnerableLibrariesLocal -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamic-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dynamic-gateway</name>
    <description>dynamic-gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <jsonwebtoken.version>0.11.5</jsonwebtoken.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```